# Error creating bean with name 'adminController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'supplierDaoImpl'

Tags: java

I've created this code and it works for me but suddenly it throws error when I run program.

> Error creating bean with name 'adminController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'supplierDaoImpl'.

```
@Component
@Entity
public class Supplier implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
private String sId;
@NotBlank(message = "Please enter Supplier Name!")
private String supplierName;

// SupplierDao

public interface SupplierDao {

boolean insertSupplier(Supplier supplier);
boolean updateSupplier(Supplier supplier);
boolean deleteSupplier(Supplier supplier);
Supplier findBySupplierId(String sid);
List<Supplier> retrieve();
}

//SupplierDaoImpl

@Repository
@Service
public class SupplierDaoImpl implements SupplierDao {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Autowired
public SupplierDaoImpl(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {

    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}

@Override
@Transactional
public boolean insertSupplier(Supplier supplier) {

    try {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.saveOrUpdate(supplier);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        return true;
    }catch(Exception exception) {
        return false;
    }
}

//HibernateConfig

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.backend.*")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class HibernateConfig
{

private final static String DATABASE_URL = "jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/emart";
private final static String DATABASE_DRIVER = "org.h2.Driver";
private final static String DATABASE_DIALECT = "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect";
private final static String DATABASE_USERNAME = "sa";
private final static String DATABASE_PASSWORD = "";

@Autowired
@Bean(name="dataSource")
public DataSource getH2Data()
{
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(DATABASE_DRIVER);
    dataSource.setUrl(DATABASE_URL);
    dataSource.setUsername(DATABASE_USERNAME);
    dataSource.setPassword(DATABASE_PASSWORD);
    System.out.println("H2 Connected"); 
    return dataSource;
}
private Properties getHiber()
{
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", DATABASE_DIALECT);
    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
    properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
    System.out.println("Tables created");
    return properties;
}
@Autowired
@Bean(name="sessionFactory")
public SessionFactory getHiberSession(DataSource dataSource)
{
    LocalSessionFactoryBuilder localSessionFactoryBuilder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource);
    localSessionFactoryBuilder.addProperties(getHiber());
    localSessionFactoryBuilder.addAnnotatedClass(User.class);
    localSessionFactoryBuilder.addAnnotatedClass(Supplier.class);
    localSessionFactoryBuilder.addAnnotatedClass(Category.class);
    localSessionFactoryBuilder.addAnnotatedClass(Products.class);

    return localSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory();
}

@Autowired
@Bean(name="supplierDaoImpl")
public SupplierDaoImpl getSupplierData(SessionFactory sessionFactory)
{
    return new SupplierDaoImpl(sessionFactory);

}

//AdminController

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/admin")
public class AdminController
{

@Autowired
SupplierDaoImpl supplierDaoImpl;


//Dispatcher Servlet

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
  xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
  xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-  3.0.xsd">

<context:annotation-config/>
 <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
 <mvc:annotation-driven/>  
<context:component-scan base-package="com.emart.controller"/>
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>

<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
<property name="maxUploadSize" value="300000000" >
</property></bean>

<mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="index" />
<mvc:resources location="/assets/" mapping="/webapp/assets/**" cache-period="31556926"/>


</beans>
```

Comment: *"but suddenly it throws error"* - programs don't *suddenly* stop working, you (or someone else) changed and broke something, trace your steps back, see what you changed and fix it.

Comment: Suddenly means when I upload it on GITHUB it's working for me but next day when I again started work on it and run it shows this error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the "getSupplierData" method from HibernateConfig class, it causes conflict with the "SupplierDaoImpl" class that annotated with "@Service" annotation